# No response from PHP Script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Absolutely new to PHP and so far it isn't pretty.
Anyway, I'm trying to pass a variable over to a PHP script, do a couple things with it, and pass it back to my Javascipt code.

Here's where I pass it off to PHP:

```
   var src=encodeURIComponent("http://www.someonlinesite.com/file.swf");
   $.ajax({
       url:'test.php?src='+src,
       dataType:'json',
       success:function(response){
           alert(response)
       }
   });
```

and here's the script:

```
<?php
   $src=isset($_GET['src'])?$_GET['src']:'';
   $size=getimagesize($src);
   echo json_encode(array('size'=>$size));
?>
```

I'm trying to pass the URL of a .SWF video file over to a small PHP script that will use `getImagesize()` to figure it's dimensions and pass them back.... but I'm not seeing anything in the response and the `alert` isn't firing.

What's going wrong?

**UPDATE**:

I've updated the code with the most recent - according to the advice from some nice SO members. When I hardcode the $src variable and navigate directly to the test.php it echoes everything perfectly. So, it looks like the PHP is working. However, it appears like either the callback is never firing or the PHP file isn't returning the data. In the console there still isn't anything in the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to concatenate your `url` string parameter in `get()`:

```
$.get('test.php?src=' + src, function(data){
   alert(data);
});
```

And also, your `src` variable begins with a double quote and is closed with a single quote. That will cause issues.

```
var src="http://www.someonelinesite.com/file.swf";
```

Also, it's probably a bad idea to do this via `$_GET` since you are passing a URL. `$_POST` would be better or [encode the URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) before you pass it. The current `url` you are passing right now would look like this in a browser:

```
http://www.mysite.com/test.php?src=http://www.someonelinesite.com/file.swf
```

That's not pretty. Using `encodeURIComponent()`, your whole URL will end up looking like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/test.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.someonelinesite.com%2Ffile.swf
```

#### Edit to $.ajax

`$.get` above would work just fine, but going with the implementation of `$.ajax` works too:

```
$.ajax({
   url:'test.php',
   type: 'GET', //Add the type
   dataType:'json',
   data: {'src': src}, //Add the data, leave it out the url
   success:function(data){
       alert(data)
   }
});
```

Comment: Hmmm... that looks like exactly how I have it. The quote issue was a typo and was ok in my code. I don't need to worry about revealing the url since I'm just wanting to call the php file, have it get the dimensions, and return the dimensions - so the url wouldn't change at all. I've switched it to post and am getting the same results.

Comment: You fixed the concatenation part? You have `'test.php?src=src`. You need to do this `'test.php?src=' + src`

Comment: Yeah, that's fixed. Any in the debugger I can see it passing in the correct path to the file. If I run the script directly it works as well. For whatever reason though it just isn't firing the callback

Comment: Just did, but must have been doing it when you posted this since I overwrote the old code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

In Jquery :

```
    var src="http://www.someonelinesite.com/file.swf";
    $.ajax({
       url:'test.php?src='+src,
       dataType:'json',
       success:function(response){
              alert(response.size);
       }
    });
```

In php

```
    $src=isset($_GET['src'])?$_GET['src']:'';  
    $size=getimagesize($src);
    echo json_encode(array('size'=>$size));
```

?>

Comment: Nope, tried this as well. If I navigate directly to the php file it pulls all the info I need. The problem is in passing that info back into the ajax request.

Comment: In jquery encode url with encodeURIComponent(src) function and passed to the ajax function

Comment: Just tried added the encoding to id, and can see the resulting character changes in the console, but still no response or callback being fired. There's been a bit of progress though so I'll update the question.

Comment: You alert an json object try this alert(response.size)

Comment: Wooo! Ok, got a response. But am now getting this warning in the response: Warning</b>:  getimagesize() [<a href='function.getimagesize'>function.getimagesize</a>]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in

Comment: getimagesize function will return an array which contain the image height, width and mime type
The server not allowing you to execute the getimagesize() may be in the configuration it is not allowed or use @getimagesize($src)